# How to compare amounts with PHP library brick/money

Tags: php, currency, money-php

I decided to use the PHP library [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money) for currency calculations, since it's too imprecise to use floats, and it's annoying to convert amounts to cents so you use integers only, and to make easier dealing with rounding. I didn't go with the [money PHP](https://github.com/moneyphp) library because it's not flexible and demands inputs to be in integer-ish form (and yeah, I'm lazy to make input/output wrappers and don't want to be debugging in cents).

I'm noticing a tiny downside of using `brick/money` since there isn't good documentation. I searched for a direct way to compare two amounts and this is a question I couldn't find an official/straightforward/direct form to do it.

So I have something like:

```
use Brick\Money\Money;

$money1 = Money::of(50, 'MXN'); // MXN 50.00
$money1 = $money1->plus('10'); // MXN 60.00 -- whatever operation

$money2 = Money::of(50, 'MXN'); // MXN 50.00
$money2 = $money1->minus('10'); // MXN 40.00 -- whatever operation
```

**Question:**
How can I compare the two amounts in *an easier way*? Do I need to call `->getMinorAmount()->toInt()` for each comparison?
Do I need to do something like the following for basic validation?:

```
if ($money1->getMinorAmount()->toInt() < 0 || 
 $money1->getMinorAmount()->toInt() < $money2->getMinorAmount()->toInt()) {
   $error = true;
}
```

Meanwhile in `money PHP` you have functions like this:

```
$result = $value1->equals($value2); 
$result = $value1->greaterThan($value2);
$result = $value1->greaterThanOrEqual($value2);
//etc...
```

Is this a missing feature or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're similar methods in the `AbstractMoney` class

```
$result = $money1->isEqualTo($money2); 
$result = $money1->isGreaterThan($money2);
$result = $money1->isGreaterThanOrEqualTo($money2);
...
```

Comment: Great! How did you find this? Did you went through all the Class definitions?

Comment: I searched "compare".